# List all dates even if not in MySQL database

Tags: mysql

The following question was closed due to it being referenced as a question that's been asked before.

It's not the same question as I have a **from** and **to** date whereas the linked question is a single date.

Can this be re-opened please?

I have the following code which works great but I would like to list all calendar dates in the "date" columns even if there is no data.

```
SELECT 
    a.date, s.*
FROM
    (SELECT 
        SUBDATE(CURDATE(), 1) + INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a)) DAY AS date
    FROM
        (SELECT 0 AS A UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS a
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS b
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS c) a
        INNER JOIN
    bookings s ON a.date >= s.check_in
        AND a.date <= s.check_out
WHERE
    check_out >= CURDATE()
ORDER BY check_out , check_in ASC;
```

Can anyone help?

Many thanks,

John

Comment: Just change `INNER JOIN bookings` to a `LEFT JOIN` and move `check_out >= CURDATE()` into the `ON` clause.